# How can I change the placement of an exterior light?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, exterior, junction-box

I have an exterior porch light with associated junction box located very near the trim around our sliding glass door. The height of this light and junction box are not optimal for lighting a broad area. I would like to install an LED wall pack having between 6,000 - 10,000 lumens and having a rectangular shape, such as something in the Lithonia TWR2 family.

Can I purchase a wet location junction box cover with hole and then run PVC, EMP, or non-metallic liquidtight conduit to the desired new wall pack light? Do I have to install a junction box behind the wall pack at the new location as well, or could I mount it to a block that stands off of the T-111 siding with no junction box?

Thank you.

[image: Current light and junction box location is circled. White rectangle is the desired new light location.]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do that. Two things to consider:

- Protection up to 8'

Wires up to 8' must have physical protection. As I understand it, only certain types of conduit - e.g., PVC 80 (but not 40) and Rigid Metal Conduit - provide that protection. Based on the picture, you are starting around 6-1/2' above the deck, so in theory the first 1-1/2' need protection. That can also be provided by wood or metal in front of the conduit, but practically speaking the solution is to use conduit that meets the physical protection requirement for the whole distance and be done.

- Junction Box for New Light

The new light needs a junction box. *Some* lights include an integral junction box just big enough for connecting one cable or set of wires to the internal wiring. Other lights don't and are designed to be mounted on a junction box. And actually the first one I found in the 6k - 10k lumen range at Home Depot has instructions for mounting on a junction box or directly on a wall with conduit. So check the specs before you buy - you may be able to avoid a separate junction box.

Comment: I would _think_ that LiquiTight meets the requirements for physical protection. I base this presumption on the number of LiquiTight whips I see running from the shut-off to exterior HVAC equipment just a foot or two off the ground. Is this a correct presumption? (Not necessarily recommending it, since it's probably the most expensive & inconvenient way of getting protection from box A to box B 7' off the ground, just looking for completeness.)

Comment: EMT doesn't provide sufficient protection?

Comment: @FreeMan My general understanding (don't know if this is spelled out in code or not) is that the whip from equipment (typically HVAC) to the wall doesn't necessarily follow the same rules as the parts installed on the wall. And logically where the rule (applied broadly even when maybe there could be some exceptions) that "on the wall below 8' needs protection because someone/some thing might bang into it" doesn't *really* apply to the cable/conduit going from wall to equipment because "you darn well better be careful working around that compressor or you'll mess things up".

Comment: @Huesmann I get these things confused. Yes, it looks like EMT qualifies. Liquidtight does not. EMT must be protected (e.g., galvanized) if used outdoors (because wet). Also rigid can support a light (luminaire) within certain constraints, EMT can't.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact but it doesn't look like the OP is asking the conduit to support a light.  At least, I'm assuming the OP plans to mount the light to the wall.  Still, my preference would be for PVC, since odds are either metal type will eventually rust.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact point taken.